# Allow Script Text in Rich Text

Tags: entries, redactor

I'm trying to configure a rich text field to allow script tags for a demo section on the page.

I added the following settings and linked this to the field

```
    {
  buttons: ['html','bold','italic','unorderedlist','orderedlist','link','image'],
  plugins: ['fullscreen'],
  toolbarFixedBox: true,
  replaceDivs: false,
  paragraphize: false,
  replaceDivs: false,
  deniedTags: [],
  removeComments: false,
  cleanSpaces: false,
  cleanOnPaste: false,
  removeDataAttr: false
}
```

However, The script tag is still always removed on save. Is there some other setting i am missing?

Comment: Why do you use a Redactor field for JS scripts to run on your site?

Comment: Following @carlcs's comment - it seems like you'd be better off putting the script code in a plain text field instead of fighting to get the WYSIWYG to let them though.

Answer (score 3):

Script tags should be put in plain text field types (if they need to be editable by the client at all, otherwise put them in the templates).